# Why can't I return an object in a Falcor router response?

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

If I use the example in the README on netflix/falcor, this works:

`return {path:['greeting'], value: 'Hello World'};`

But if I try to change the value to an object:

`return {path:['greeting'], value: {hello: 'Hello World'}};`

It doesn't seem to work. I'm probably doing something obviously wrong, but I wanted to get some clarification.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the model is requesting the data?

Comment: Phi Nguyen answered it. I'd read the docs but it had been a few days and the elegance of Falcor is so nice I forgot about Jafar Husain explaining why objects and arrays aren't allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Falcor doesn't allow to return value as Object or Array because of scalability reason. [Here](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/model.html) is the explanation for it.

> Both Arrays and Objects can contain an unbounded amount of data. Requesting an Array or Object in its entirety is equivalent to your view requesting ‘SELECT *’ without a ‘WHERE’ clause in the SQL world. An Array that contains 5 items today, can grow to contain 10,000 items later on. This means that requests which are initially served quickly and fit the view’s requirements can become slower over time as more data is added to backend data stores.

There are some cases, you want to return an array, an object. You should use [Atom type](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/model.html#JSON-Graph-Atoms) of JSON Graph.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below one of the solutions

```
var $atom = Falcor.Model.atom;

return {path:["items"], value: $atom(data.items)};
```

For more information kindly visit [this link](https://gist.github.com/designeng/f00de5e04f27773eaf5c#file-itemsrouter_improved-js-L1-L20)